# Mysql журнал запросов в базу данных

Tags: c#, mysql

десктоп приложение winforms с базой данных mysql. пользователи логинятся через базу данных при заходе в форму. в базе стоит таблица с юзерами (логин, пароль, статус, отдел) . теперь как мне контролировать юзеров, узнать какой юзер когда и где какие запросы сделал ( изменил запись, удалил или добавил). настроил глобальный лог файл (general_log.CSV) но там общий юзер указан

```
2022-05-24 10:22:12.646866,"admin[admin] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]",112,1,"Query","SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'"
```

а мне нужен тот юзер который при заходе в приложение указал логин пароль. помогите пожалуйста разобраться

таблица юзеров выглядит следующим образом

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`login` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`parol` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `status_id` (`status_id`),
KEY `department_id` (`department_id`),
CONSTRAINT `loginDepartmentID` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`) ON 
DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `loginStatusID` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `status` (`id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



 class conString
{
    public static MySqlConnection
        
        GetDBConnection(string host, int port, string database, string username, string password)
    {
        // Connection String.
        String connString = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database
            + ";port=" + port + ";User Id=" + username + ";password=" + password;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        return con;
    }
}
class ConDatabase
{
    public static MySqlConnection GetDBConnection()
    {
        string host = "192.168.1.107";
        int port = 3306;
        string database = "dslamauditnew";
        string username = "admin";
        string password = "12345"; 

        return conString.GetDBConnection(host, port, database, username, password);
    }
}

 MySqlConnection con = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection();
```

Comment: Надо создавать свою собственную систему логирования.

Comment: @aepot,  библиотека Nlog не подойдет ?

Comment: MySQL в принципе не может знать о пользователях прикладного уровня. *мне нужен тот юзер который при заходе в приложение указал логин пароль.* Но ведь логин и пароль тоже проверяются запросом, верно? значит, этот запрос тоже присутствует в логе, причём с конкретными значениями, и он выполнен в соединении с конкретным номером. Вот тебе уже связка логина и номера соединения. И соответственно ты знаешь по номеру соединения, какой логин в приложении выполнил запрос, для всех остальных запросов этого соединения.

Comment: Конечно, если приложение не использует постоянное соединение, а переоткрывает их на каждый чих, то этот метод недоступен. Но это опять не проблема в MySQL, это проблема того, кто так написал клиента.

Comment: @Akina, простите,  насчет постоянного соединение имеете ввиду использование  Using который обрывает соединение ?

Comment: Я имею в виду именно соединение. И именно при взгляде со стороны MySQL. Что там на стороне приложения - понятия не имею. Какое-нибудь connection.open, возможно...

Comment: пользователь при входе вводит логин пароль статус, а это запрос в базу, но почему то не видно в журнале логов какой IP адрес сделал запрос ,и да при каждом запросе соединение открывается и закрывается, если не трудно  посмотрите пожалуйста запрос в базу данных со стороны клиента . выложу код